# Wysiwyg image upload product weird URL?

Tags: product, image, wysiwyg, magento2.1.0

When I try to add images to the wysiwyg editor on a product I get a url like below

```
https://domain.co.uk/admin/cms/wysiwyg/directive/___directive/e3ttZWRpYSB1cmw9Ind5c2l3eWcvc3F1YXJlX2JveF93ZWxkXzEuanBnIn19/key/d572120a6df9ab6f1c29f11eec2a1059c1ea6a76caadd2ede6cc2396664ab65d/
```

Needless to say these images don't display, what is happening? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Please change this setting and check

```
Admin->System->Configuration->General(Content Management)->WYSIWYG Options->Use Static URLs for Media Content in WYSIWYG for Catalog
```

Change this to "Yes".

Comment: Thanks, but.. "Media content is not updated if the system configuration base URL changes." I need to be able to update the base URL, should I really be switching this on? Why doesn't it just work?

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue, but changing **Use Static URLs for Media Content in WYSIWYG for Catalog to yes** does not resolve for me. From what i see magento 2 is creating a  directive through the admin url so if you are not logged in then the image wont load. this is a security issue also because its disclosing the admin url